# onchange of SELECT element I want the next INPUT element need to be changed. INPUT elements are named in array "quest[]"

Tags: javascript, jquery, siblings

With for loop multiple input and select elements are generated. Those elements are named as name="quest[]".

Now I trigger a select button and changge the value. Based on the value I want the adjusant INPUT element to be hidden/ shown. How to do this

How to identify the adjusant INPUT box and place a value inside them.

```
function frt_time(val) {
var y =val ;
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
x[4].value = '';

    if (y == "RETURN"){
        x[4].style.display = 'block';//show
    }else{
        x[4].value = '';
        x[4].style.display = 'none';//Hide
    }   
}
```

Comment: You want determine value of input and hide for some reason ? IDK why you are use ``y = val`` and later ``y == "RETURN"``, more sense for this is used on if condition ``x[some_index].value == "RETURN"``

Comment: If you can add your html and explain a bit more, will be good.

Comment: RETURN or NOT RETURN are the selection field values.

Comment: Add your html please.

Comment: @deon cagadoes kindly have look. https://jsfiddle.net/20ARUNCHENNAI19/ku2qjyme/12/

Comment: You are referring to hide all inputs ? When you select no return ?

Comment: presently, when I change the select field (i.e 2nd field ) to "RETURN" the 4th INPUT alone I could able to hide (by marking x[4]. How can I hide 8th INPUT when I change the 4th field SELECT field and so on..

Comment: ``if (val == "RETURN") {
        x[4].style.display = 'block'; //show
        x[8].style.display = 'none' //hide
      }`` You are referring to this ?

Comment: yes. This is what I'm reffering to.

Comment: Need more help ? Can i answer with the code i put ?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (document.getElementsByTagName("select").val() === "Something"){
  frt_time(document.getElementsByTagName("select").val())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select').change(function(){
  var input = $(this).find('+ input')
  switch($(this).val()){
    case '1': input.hide(); break
    case '2': input.show(); break
  }
})
```